# How to convert an HTML String to PDF using wkhtmltopdf or wkhtmltoImage in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltoimage

I am using wkhtmltoPDF to generate pdf from html string and It works fine for me as expected, but now I have to generate output as Image and I'm unable to find sample code or any library.

I have referred  https://github.com/jhonnymertz/java-wkhtmltopdf-wrapper to generate pdf.

```
import com.github.jhonnymertz.wkhtmltopdf.wrapper.Pdf;

public class WKhtmlToPdf
 { 
    Pdf pdf = new Pdf();
    pdf.addPageFromString("html code");
    pdf.addToc();

 try{
     pdf.saveAs("Output.pdf");
   }
    catch (IOException e)
     {
     }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
     {     
     }
 }
```

I wanted an output an Image. Can any one tell me and I don't want to use  **Runtime.getRuntime().exe()** method to generate output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In java HTML can rendered with OpenFX or swing (less well), and then drawn to an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) is a library which is part of the **wkhtmltox** project, which includes **wkhtmltoimage** too. You can inspire yourself from the wrapper you linked above to develop a wkhtmltoimage wrapper.

Also, I generally use [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/) to generate images programmatically. [IM4Java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/) is an example wrapper to it for Java.

Comment: Thanks @OlivierH, I tried and then only posted question.

Comment: They have given example  of  pdf only  not for Image output.

Comment: @Deva What are you talking about ? IM4Java or java-wkhtmltopdf-wrapper ?

Comment: I am talking about  java-wkhtmltopdf-wrapper.  They have not given docs proper way about how to convert html to image. they only gave html to pdf.

Comment: You are right, this wrapper cannot generate images at this  moment. What I meant is that you can clone this project and  change it to output images instead of pdf : wkhtmltopdf and wkhtmltoimage are very similar in their use.

Comment: Thanks @OlivierH. Thanks for your support.